# HTML object library / pull

Tags: html, vba, web-scraping

I have the following code in an HTML web page, and I am trying to use the html object library via vba engine to pull the value from within this tag:

```
<input name="txtAdd_Line1" disabled="disabled" size="30" maxLength="50" value="123 N 1ST ST"/>
```

I figure I have to use `.getelementsbytagname` or `.getelementsbyname`, but I am not sure how to grab the value.  Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Tagged as VB6 and VBScript but the question mentions only VBA.  What gives?

Comment: @Bob77 Looks like the accepted answer was in VBA too, so I'll re-tag.

Comment: @jason VB, VBA, VBScript, VB.NET are all similar languages but not identical, so it's important to specify the correct one when tagging questions (or when googling for information!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example with comments, subtitute in your actual address:

```
Sub Example()
    'Declare needed variables
    Dim ie, elements
    Dim x As Long
    'Create IE Applction
    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    'Navigate to the website
    ie.navigate "C:\test.html" 'Substitute your actual address
    'Wait for website to finish loading
    Do While ie.ReadyState <> 4
    Loop

    'Find the elements
    Set elements = ie.document.getelementsbyName("txtAdd_Line1")
    'Display the value of each returned element
    For x = 0 To elements.Length - 1
        MsgBox elements(x).Value
    Next
    'Quit IE
    ie.Quit
End Sub
```

Based on your comment most likely just looking at the document wasn't retrieving the actual layer of the tree you wanted, try this:

```
Set HTMLDoc = ie.document.frames("MainFrame").document 
With HTMLDoc 
    'This returns an (object) which contains an array of all matching elements
    a = .getElementsByName("txtAdd_Line1")
end with
For x = 0 to a.length
    msgbox a(x).value
next
```

Comment: i tried running through that line by line and it skips over `MsgBox elements(x).Value` and is somehow returning <out of context> value for 'elements', but thank you for giving me a great starting point! I also tried doing `Set HTMLDoc = ie.document.frames("MainFrame").document` `With HTMLDoc` `a = .getElementsByName("txtAdd_Line1")` and it returns a as [object]

Comment: Added some code that may get you want you need based on the additional information you just gave me. The problem with the previous code is that I guess it was searching the wrong document, since your actual document is inside a frame in the parent document... yay.

Comment: I am getting Runtime Error 438: Object does not support this property or method for `For x = 0 To a.Length`

Comment: Mind sharing more of the HTML? I made my own small page to test on and can't get it to fail. :(

Comment: Actually, I thought about it and there wouldn't be a need to pull it into an array since each element name is unique on the page. `With HTMLDoc` `A = .getElementsByName("txtAdd_Line1")` `End With` `MsgBox A.Value` This works perfect. Thank you for your help on this! I appreciate your time

Answer (score 0):

You can use a CSS selector of `input[name='txtAdd_Line1']` . This says element with `input` tag having attribute `name` with value `'txtAdd_Line1'`.

CSS selector:

[image: CSS selector]

You apply a CSS selector using the [`.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) method of `document` e.g.

```
Msgbox ie.document.querySelector("input[name='txtAdd_Line1']").innerText
```